# Windows 7 embedded

Tags: windows, windows-embedded

Due to turn windows  features on or off is blank, so I need to install IIS using command line, How can I install default IIS using command line?

Comment: I am wondering why this question voted down without any reason! if you do not understand, just let me know to explain further

Comment: I am wondering why my answer voted down without any reason!

Comment: Your answer is voted down because on `embedded` system, there're only a few items in the optional features. You are supposed to select everything you need before the system is installed

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to it. See: http://reboot.pro/topic/16383-windows-embedded-standard-7-add-packages-on-a-live-image/

Basically you need to get the `.cab` package from the installation dvd and then feed it to `DISM`, like: `DISM.exe /online /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\Temp /NoRestart`

Answer (score -1):

Have you try to use the **optionalfeatures** command? Are you administrator on the computer?

[image]

Also you can try the [DISM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/habibh/2009/08/14/how-to-install-iis-7-5-on-windows-7-using-the-command-line/) if the above doesn't work for you.